# How to insert an entity and keep the same Object Guid with EF

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I need keep the same original Id (GUID) after save data because is a replication job. (SQL -> SQL remote). Then, the model can not be changed. After SaveChanges() EF insert a new random Guid as Id, then this changes my original object, and do not want that. A compact sample:

```
class EFInsertTest
{
    public void InsertTest()
    {
        var id = new Guid("D75C887D-BF25-E611-943B-080027BA87E8"); // dummy

        var entity = new Something { Id = id, Name = "ELENOR" };

        using (var db = new SomethingContext())
        {
            db.Things.Add(entity);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // TEST
            if (db.Things.Find(id) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Great! Expected behavior");
            }
            else
            {// run this:
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed! Id has another value");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

            // SQL hard code (works fine)
            db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"INSERT INTO [Something] VALUES('{id}', '{entity.Name}')");
            db.SaveChanges();

            // TEST
            if (db.Things.Find(id) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Great! Expected behavior");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed! Id has another value");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}

public class SomethingContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Something> Things { get; set; }
}

public class Something
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, apparently in the EF model the Id is defined as database-generated.

Comment: Use [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]